# Proper way to handle ant build for an Android Library. Build is excluding R.class from jar file

Tags: android, ant, build

Currently running into an issue where our production build using ant excludes the R.class file. Looking at the ADT build.xml, I see this:

```xml
<if condition="${project.is.library}">
<then>
...
    <jar destfile="${out.library.jar.file}">
        <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
            includes="**/*.class"
            excludes="${project.app.package.path}/R.class ${project.app.package.path}/R$*.class ${project.app.package.path}/BuildConfig.class"/>
        <fileset dir="${source.absolute.dir}"
            excludes="**/*.java ${android.package.excludes}" />
</jar>
</then>
</if>
```

Currently the build grabs the classes.jar file but as you can see above this doesn't include the R.class file so when the library attempts to grab an externalized string it explodes on an `NoClassDefFoundError`

**Update:**
Found the following quote here: http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects

> Important change:
>
> We have changed the way Library Projects generate and package R classes:
>
> - The R class is not packaged in the jar output of Library Projects anymore.
> - Library Project do not generate the R class for Library Projects they depend on. Only main application projects generates the Library R classes alongside their own.
>
> This means that library projects cannot import the R class from another library project they depend on. This is not necessary anyway, as their own R class includes all the necessary resources.
>   Note that app projects can still import the R classes from referenced Library Projects, but again, this is not needed as their own R classes include all the resources.

So, given this, what's the proper way to package an Android library project?

**Update 2:**
So we worked around this issue by manually packaging the R.class and R$*.class files into the jar.

I don't know if this is the "proper" way to package an Android library, since the ADT build scripts strip these out. If no one suggests a more "proper" way to do this I'll submit this as the answer for this.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. Library Projects with resources cannot be packaged as jars.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations - "You cannot export a library project to a JAR file". It says "it will be added in a future version", but AFAIK that never happened.

Answer (score 1):

Good day.

1. R class does not packaged in output jar because it can conflict with R class of main project.
2. When You refer to library project from main project and build it with ant sript that Android SDK contains it cretes R file with package of library.
3. If You want to create android library with compiled source code, You can compile java code only. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9644990/1145140) You can find a solution.
4. It's not nessesarily to pack R file to compiled jar. You can acces resources via [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) class. For example:

   ```
   setContentView(getResources().getIdentifier("your_layout_id", "layout", getPackageName()));
   // is equals to setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add

```
<src path="../src"/>
<src path="../gen"/>
```

to  `<javac>:`

Source: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990724/ant-failing-to-import-r-java)